# Virtualbox error when starting win7 machine

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox

I created a Ubuntu 18.04x64 VM and into this I installed the `virtualbox` and created a windows7x64 VM, but, when I start this win7 VM I got this error bellow:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine win7.
VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)
Result code: NS-ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: |Console {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

I checked the Nested VT-x/AMD-V option in the system>processor.

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: What is your CPU model?

Comment: @N0rbert my laptop processor is a i7.